# JMeter insert all records from CSV to sql database

Tags: mysql, csv, jmeter, bulkinsert

I have large amount of data from master DB which I am reading and writing into CSV by applying some logic to clean the data. This is a large data set of over 100K.
I am using beanshell to write to CSV which is very fast.

Now the ultimate goal is to write that data into next mySQL DB.

Ideally I would like not to have CSV involved and directly write to mySQL DB but that may have an issue which is that then I would need to have JDBC step added to call it for 100k records.

So i am thinking to still write to the CSV and from there I would like to split the records in to 1000 or 2000 set to reduce the load on SQL query.

Note: I cannot remove the beanshell part because i am parsing the JSON response and then writing to CSV so something has to be worked out with it.

Any suggestion solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So add a new database copy the data from first to the new database apply your changes to clean up, rename first database and then the second and keep the original till your next clean up next time. the databases can be on the same server. Of course you need to program your clean up algorithm in sql

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert the whole CSV into the MySQL database the fastest and the easiest way is using [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) statement, something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' INTO TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
```

---

I would also recommend reconsidering your "beanshell" approach, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, [Groovy performs much better](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) and has [built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) (as well as [SQL support](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)) .